# Center the text in whole page

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

I have just a single line on one page. I want to bring it on the center of page both through length and breadth. How can it be done?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My try:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
\
\vfil
\hfil Centered text \hfil
\vfil
\end{document}
```

Comment: Damn, you were quicker by a few seconds ;-)

Comment: Thanks it worked. What if the text is in three lines?

Comment: Then suppress the `\hfil`  commands and insert the `\centering` command just before your text (or enclose this text in a `center` environment).

Answer (score 9):

You can use `\vspace` command as it follows :

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\vspace*{\stretch{1}}
Your text centered
\vspace*{\stretch{1}}
\end{center}

\clearpage    

\end{document}
```

It works without text before and the text centered can be as long as possible (one page). `\stretch` makes nice effects.

Comment: `\clearpage` should be added, if more pages follow.

Comment: This is not horizontally centered for me.

Comment: You also need a `center` environment, if you want horizontal centering

Comment: Yes, egreg is right. Before you may use \begin{center} and at the end \end{center}.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paper=a6paper]{geometry}% Just for this example
\pagestyle{empty}% Just for this example

\begin{document}
\vspace*{\fill}% * is needed here
\noindent
\makebox[\textwidth]{\Huge SoMeTHiNG}

\vfill
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using picture mode via [`eso-pic`](http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) is straight forward:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{eso-pic,xcolor}

\usepackage[paper=a6paper]{geometry}% Just for this example
\pagestyle{empty}% Just for this example

\begin{document}

\AddToShipoutPictureFG{% Add content to page ForeGround
  \AtPageCenter{% Add content to page centre
    \raisebox{-.5\height}{\makebox[0pt]{%
      \Huge SoMeTHiNG%
    }}
  }
}

\mbox{}% Just for something on the page

\clearpage

% Comparison to http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/285473/5764
\vspace*{\stretch{1}}
{\centering\Huge\textcolor{black!50}{SoMeTHiNG}\par}%
\vspace*{\stretch{1}}

\end{document}
```